# How to include a class from outside of cakephp folder

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4

Please see my current file structure

```
CakePHP
  - bin
  - config
  - src
  - vendor
  - webroot


RowPHP
  - push.php
```

I want to `import/include` Push class into my cakephp2 application which stands at push.php file outside of cakephp

### Which I have tried

```
require_once( ROOT . DS . '..' . DS . 'RowPHP'. DS . 'push.php');
$pushOb = new Push();
```

it include successfully but when I try to create a object it through error

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\Push' not found

Question: How to import/include this class into my cakephp application ?

Comment: That looks to be an issue with namespacing. Have you tried using `new \Push()`?

Comment: OMG !!!! It's Working..... Thanks a lot @drmonkeyninja

Comment: No problem. I've added it as an answer so that others can find the solution more easily. Would you mind accepting it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure PHP can find the class in the correct namespace using `new \Push()` (note the backslash before the class name):-

```
require_once( ROOT . DS . '..' . DS . 'RowPHP'. DS . 'push.php');
$pushOb = new \Push();
```